# Want to add text box div inside content div

Tags: html, css, youtube, margin

quick note: I just started learning HTML yesterday, this is incredibly  new to me so don't be too harsh please--that said, if anyone sees any code that could be done in a simpler way or has any random advice outside of what I'm requesting, please don't hesitate to share. I have a feeling this is terribly scripted, this site is more to help me learn html than for actual use, so there are some area's where I was just using trial and error to make certain things work, and as a result you might see unnecessary code lying around. Point that out too if it bugs you!

ANYWAY, on to the point of the post. I want to have div.textbox inside of div.contentbg with margin-top: 15px. When I try this, however, it applies the margin to div.contentbg instead of div.textbox... it's probably something really stupid. Any help? Thanks in advance! :D

Here's the site: http://jsfiddle.net/gbk8zhwv/1/embedded/result/

Here's the code:

```css
<html> <title>JBROblivion</title> <head> <style> * {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
body {
  background-color: black;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px !important;
  height: 100%;
}
a {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
img {
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
div.contentbg {
  background-color: #660000;
  width: 1000px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
div.textbox {
  width: 90%;
  margin: 0px auto;
}
div.lrmipsm {
  width: 500px;
}
#nav {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #5C0000;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #853333;
}
#nav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  width: 1000px;
}
#nav li {
  float: left;
}
#nav li a:link,
a:visited {
  display: block;
  padding: 15px;
  width: 170px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #000000;
  background-color: #5C0000;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: "Century Gothic", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
#nav li a:hover,
a:active {
  background-color: #520000;
}
h1.centre {
  font-family: "Century Gothic", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
p.introblock {
  font-family: "Century Gothic", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
</style> </head>
```

```html
<body>

  <img src="http://yt3.ggpht.com/-HKi7fjQseQ0/VJzF49SbsxI/AAAAAAAAAJI/zbpOKJ0Uy0E/w2120-fcrop64=1,00005a57ffffa5a8-nd/Channel%2BArt%2BMask.jpg" alt="Banner" width="100%">

  <div id="nav">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="default.htm">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="about.htm">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="milestones.htm">Milestones</a></li>
      <li><a href="shop.htm">Shop</a></li>
      <li><a href="https://www.youtube.com/user/JBROblivion" target="_blank">Youtube</a> </li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="contentbg">
    <div class="textbox">

      <h1 class="centre">Intro</h1>
      <br>
      <div class="lrmipsm">
        <p class="introblock">Lorem ipsum... sample text.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: does padding-top work on textbox instead?

Comment: try adding `<div class="contentbg">&nbsp;`

Comment: @SharpCode I added padding-top to h1.centre and that worked. However when I tried to replace the 2 divs with 1 div with padding applied ie:

`div.contentbg  {
 background-color: #660000;
 width: 900px;
 padding: 50px 20px 0px 50px;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
  }`

nothing happened...

Comment: See my answer below. It might be best to keep 2 divs then. Would need to see your code for the 1 div example to fix that.

Comment: Just tested with my example code. I removed the first div and changed margin-top to padding-top and it worked. You might be doing something really simple wrong. Recheck your code.

Answer (score 1):

The reason it does not work is because `contentbg` does not actually have any of its own content. Notice in the example how it works when you run it because there is content in the first div. If you remove "This is some content" it will not appear to work because there is no content to workout where to begin marginalizing (for lack of a better word) from.

**Example**

```css
div {
    background-color: yellow;
}

div.ex {
    background-color:red;
    margin-top: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div>This is some content
    <div class="ex">This is some content on the inner div.</div>
</div>
```

In the case you have a div like yours that is empty I would suggest using the padding property instead. This will leave the divs where they are and instead produce some padding around the content of the div you require padding on.